# Proper arrangement of nodes in graph

Tags: nodes

See what i made in below example.
You can observe that in my graph there are six nodes.
Now my question is How can i put all this nodes manually without using \foreach.
Because in graph some nodes are not properly arranged.[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,latex-latex] (-8,0) -- (8,0)node[right]{$x$};
\draw[thick,latex-latex] (0,-8) -- (0,8)node[above]{$y$};
\node at (-0.3,-0.3) {O};
\foreach \x/\l in {-7/-7,-6/-6,-5/-5,-4/-4,-3/-3,-2/-2,-1/-1,1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4,5/5,6/6,7/7}{
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below:$\l$] at (\x,0) {};
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=left:$\l$] at (0,\x) {};
}
\draw[thick,stealth-stealth, shorten >= -1cm, shorten <= -1cm,name path =b ](-7,5) --(0,6)-- (7,7);
\draw[thick,stealth-stealth, shorten >= -2cm, shorten <= -2cm](0,-2)-- (3, -1) -- (6,0) ;

\foreach \x/\y/\name in {0/6/,-7/5/,7/7/}{
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2.5pt,label={[inner sep=2pt]above right:\name($\x, \y$)}] at (\x,\y) {};
};
\foreach \x/\y/\name in {0/-2/,3/-1/,6/0/}{
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2.5pt,label={[inner sep=12pt]below right:\name($\x, \y$)}] at (\x,\y) {};
};
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2.5pt,label={(2, 3)}] at (2,3) {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are making axis and plots, you can use `pgfplots`. Here you can also use `tikz` package, to draw simple figures, by `(axis cs: x,y)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    domain = -8:8,
    xmin = -8,
    xmax = 8,
    ymin = -8,
    ymax = 8,
    x=1cm,
    y=1cm,
    thick,
]
\draw[fill] (axis cs: -7,5) node[above] {$(-7,5)$} circle(2pt)
    -- (axis cs: 0,6)  node[above right] {$(0,6)$} circle(2pt)
    -- (axis cs: 7,7) node[above] {$(7,7)$} circle(2pt);
\path (axis cs: -7,5) -- (axis cs: 7,7) coordinate[pos=-1/20] (A);      
\path (axis cs: 7,7) -- (axis cs: -7,5) coordinate[pos=-1/20] (B);   
\draw[->] (axis cs: -7,5) -- (A);
\draw[->] (axis cs: 7,7) -- (B);
%or you could do it like this
\draw[fill] (axis cs: 0,-2) node[below right] {$(0,-2)$} circle(2pt);
\draw[fill] (axis cs: 3,-1) node[below right] {$(3,-1)$} circle(2pt);
\draw[fill] (axis cs: 6,0)  node[above left] {$(6,0)$} circle(2pt);
\addplot[<->,domain=-0.15:1.15,variable=\t] 
({\t*(0)+(1-\t)*6},{\t*(-2)+(1-\t)*0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: i am looking for lines passing through the given points.

Comment: In your answer we can see line segment.

Comment: waiting for your reply. how could i get the same. <------>

Comment: Line should be extended for at least 1 cm. from both sides

Comment: Then you must say what points are given, and I'll try to modify the code...

Comment: Exactly i need a line passing through three points namely (-7,5), (0,6),(7, 7) which is already in your code but it is in form of line segment.

Comment: In similar manner i am looking forward for the second line passing through (0, -2), (3, -1) and (6, 0)

Comment: Big thanks.. you done it. Thanks a lot. one more question

Comment: Suppose i want same outputs through my codes, how we can make it possible. I am eagerly waiting for answer.

Comment: I don't understand question. If you mean changes in font, it happens because mathform $...$ has its own fonts, different from others, they are stored in the main directory. Also font size, sometimes, must be corrected locally.